# Adding account and more user-friendly integration into Twitch bot

Tags: python, irc, twitch

Lately, I've worked on a chat bot of my own for twitch.tv, connecting using the IRC channel and using a python script as well as logs from HexChat, my IRC client, to build my bot, which currently can give(upon query) the uptime of the channel, and statistics on emotes in the channel.

However, I have seen Moobot and Nightbot, 2 of the most popular chat bots on twitch, and was wondering how I could:

1) Turn this python script into something a streamer can authorize to be on their channel,

2) Hook up a GUI to this, or a series of text fields for the user to input their settings for the bot while it runs on their channel.

I have looked at previous questions on StackOverflow, looked on Google, and asked in the #twitch-api IRC channel on freenode, however none of these provided the answer, and the only bots I have seen that have this channel-bot integration and authorization are Moobot and Nightbot. Upon clicking "connect to twitch" on moobot's homepage, I can authorize it to use my account much like an oauth request, however I do not know how to set this up. I hope this will help others like me wanting to add some extra usability to their WIP Twitch Chat bot. Thanks!

Moobot: http://twitch.moobot.tv/

Nightbot: https://www.nightbot.tv/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most of the "big" server-hosted bots consist of 4 major parts:

1. A database (SQL or NoSQL) holding all the settings etc.
2. A REST (or similar) API that is used to communicate between the individual parts
3. A web application for the frontend
4. A standalone bot for the backend

Keep in mind that this is alot of work to set up. I am currently working on a full rewrite of my bot, which I would share if it wasnt in a pre-alpha state.

Keep in mind that setting up these individual parts might require an experienced web developer. Here is some tips however:
Using python, [Django](https://www.djangoproject.com/) is a great decision for a web application + API backend
As far as I know, there is no decent IRC library for python supporting [IRC v3](http://ircv3.net/) so you might have to implement your own. [Sample implementation of the message parser](https://gist.github.com/CBenni/680ccc4d95842ed60079)

Apart from that, see the Twitch.tv [API documentation](https://github.com/justintv/Twitch-API/tree/master/v3_resources) - this includes the Authentification workflow.

---

If you are looking for a locally-hosted bot, that's a completely different thing to deal with. There is a fair amount of those, some of which are open source too. I dont know any low-level ones, but maybe looking at [Botnak](https://github.com/Gocnak/Botnak), made by a friend of mine, answers some questions.

Comment: Thanks so much for the extensive answer! I think I will locally host it for now, until it becomes popular enough where having it set up on servers would be necessary. Otherwise, you've given me plenty to work on after I finish with all that I can do without being integrated into a twitch account, then looking forward to working out the auth, learning some Django, and overrall setting this up! Thanks again!